# Where do I find the pricing for the different frontend instance types?

Tags: google-app-engine

I cannot find the pricing for the different frontend instance classes for app engine (F1, F2, F4, F4_1G).
Why is it not under Pricing/Quota or somewhere in the page explaining the appengine-web.xml?

Comment: FWIW, Google accepted the issue I files for this: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12932

Comment: [Google Appengine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be an explicit note for this in the documentation, which is now gone.

I did capture a snapshot of it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460138/4495081

I can only assume the pricing model explained in the note is still applicable :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the documentation moved here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes

Update - it's now here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing