# Can I change the instance class of Node.js app on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I deployed my node.js app to Google App Engine. However, it automatically used two g1-small instances under Compute Engine, and there was no room I can set the instance class beforehand.

Because it is insanely expensive to use two such large instances, however, I want to change the instance class.

However, it seems that there are no columns there that let me change it, and [a similar question hasn't got any accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454741/not-able-to-change-the-frontend-instance-class-in-appengine-application), though it is on Python, not node.js.

So is it feasible to change the instance type on Google App Engine? I want to use f1-micro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained here in the resource settings

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

you don't explicitly defined the instance type, but you defined the cpu and memory

Comment: Thanks. It seems working but when I set it tiny enough (e.g. cpu: .05, memory_gb: .05), more instances are going to pop up (now I have 8 f1-micro instances), which doesn't let me suppress the cost...